# How to recreate the arrow next to the icon of each tumblr post?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr

It's viewable right on the homepage: tumblr.com

I am more curious than anything, as I usually do not go into such design detail on my web applications. I am guessing that using javascript to modify the border would be overkill here or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tumblr uses a tiny span (`.arrow`) inside the post div and positions it with the following css:

```
width: 12px;
height: 23px;
background: url("/images/dashboard_master_sprite.png?2") no-repeat -396px -247px transparent;
position: absolute;
left: -11px;
top: 22px;
```

As you can see there is an image (the arrow) as the background for the span and the width and height is set in order to make the span visible.

The absolute tag allows the overlapping (although not exactly overlapping literally the positioning overlaps the outer div ) and it is set to be `22px` from the top and `-11px` to the left making it 'pop' out of the div.

Using javascript would really be overkill and client heavy. Don't do it. Most sites that need this sort of thing use this method because it is light and it works, although personally i prefer to have my ui's purely css/html.